# How to solve using Fermat's Little Theorem on large numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Does anyone know how to solve $2032^{3366}\pmod{3359}$?

So far I managed to get,
$$ 2032^{3366} \equiv 2032^{8}\pmod{3359} $$

Now I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: You might actually have to do some arithmetic.

Comment: You just have to square $2032$ three times $\pmod{3359}$. Even the calculator in Windows 10 (scientific mode) has both $x^2$ and $\pmod{}$.

Comment: it should be $845$